# How can I make list item with uniform length?

Tags: html, css, tabs, grid

I am creating an unordered list for horizontal tab component. I want each list item filling in one of three boxes with uniform length and height shown on the image. Here is my jsFiddle and javascript. What should I change on CSS to make this happen?

```
$(function(){
    $('#tabs').tabs({
        event: "mouseover"
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m1xhc4v5/6/

Comment: What image? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Somehow, stackoverflow did not show the image. I could only reupload the image tomorrow.

Comment: https://na.cx/i/a7J56X.png my design

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add these three values to your css:

```
 #tabs li{
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    width: 30%;
}
```

You need to make an element inline-block for it to receive a width. I used 30% to allow for the borders, you can fine-tune this to what ever value you like.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m1xhc4v5/8/)